# how to replace multiple factors in whole data.frame in R

Tags: r

i would like to replace various factors in a data.frame with another factor (that is not part of the levels). For instance:

```
au1 <- c('deb', 'art', 'deb', 'seb', 'deb', 'deb', 'mar', 'mar', 'joy', 'deb')
au2 <- c('art', 'deb', 'soy', 'deb', 'joy', 'ani', 'deb', 'deb', 'nem', 'mar')
au3 <- c('mar', 'lio', 'mil', 'mar', 'ani', 'lul', 'nem', 'art', 'deb', 'tat')

tata <- data.frame(au1, au2, au3)
```

I would like to change all the 'deb' and 'joy' with 'XXX'.

Can't find a way to do that. I struggle with adding a level to a whole data.frame and with the use of %in% c('', '') for a data.frame.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A data.frame is a list. You cannot simply change the levels for a whole list, you need to iterate over the list content:

```
as.data.frame(
  lapply(tata, function(x) {
    levels(x)[levels(x) %in% c("deb", "joy")] <- "XXX"
    x
  }))
```

Comment: OK thanks it works great. I couldn't get over the list issue.

Answer (score 5):

You could use function `mapvalues()` from library `plyr()`. As you want to do this this with multiple columns then you can use also function `sapply()`. This solution works if all columns in your data frame are factors.

```
library(plyr)
xx<-as.data.frame(sapply(tata,
          mapvalues, from = c("deb", "joy"), to = c("XXX", "XXX")))
```

Comment: thanks it works well too. Although I am less confortable with this code. What is intereting is that you can also change values for each one separately. I get the following report: "the following 'from' values were nor present in 'x': joy" but it works.

Comment: @JeanUbai It is just warning because some of your factors didn't have level 'joy'.

Comment: ok. The good thing is that your code answers what my next problem was going to be!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the `NAer` function from the qdap package:

```
library(qdap)

tata[apply(tata, 2,  '%in%', c('deb', 'joy'))] <- NA
NAer(tata, "XXX")

##    au1 au2 au3
## 1  XXX art mar
## 2  art XXX lio
## 3  XXX soy mil
## 4  seb XXX mar
## 5  XXX XXX ani
## 6  XXX ani lul
## 7  mar XXX nem
## 8  mar XXX art
## 9  XXX nem XXX
## 10 XXX mar tat
```